# extract profile from Android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am writing an app that relies on pulling the user's name and profile picture on their phone. I know that I can do the following:

```
// Retrieve owner's name
String[] fields = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI};
Cursor curs = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, fields, null, null, null);
if (curs != null) {
    curs.moveToFirst();
    if (curs.getCount() > 0){
        profile.put(NAME, curs.getString(0));
        ContactPickerActivity.name = curs.getString(0);
        profile.put(PIC, curs.getString(1));
        ContactPickerActivity.imageUri = curs.getString(1);
    }
    curs.close();
 }
 toDisplay += "Owner of phone: " + profile.get(NAME) + "\n";
```

The problem with this is that it only works for API 14 and later. Is there any similar methods that work earlier versions?